# Rails 4 - How to query a has_many model to find objects based on associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am running Rails 4 on Heroku using Devise gem.

I have two models in question: posts and votes.  I am trying to find all posts that a user has not yet voted on.  I cannot figure out the proper way to use rails ActiveRecord to make this query.  So far, I have tried:

```
@posts = Post.includes(:votes).where('votes.user_id != ?', current_user.id)
```

and I have tried:

```
@posts = Post.joins(:votes).where.not( votes: {user_id: current_user.id})
```

which did not fetch any results.

In the model, I have the Has_many relationship set up as:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :images, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :votes, dependent: :destroy
end
```

This is probably an easy question for someone who is more experienced to answer, but I have tried searching through [RailsGuides Active Record Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) to no avail.

Comment: can we see the error?

Comment: Sorry - wasn't an error, just no records returned. (when indeed there are 3 records that should have been returned).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
@posts = Post.includes(:votes).where('votes.user_id <> ? or votes.user_id is null', current_user.id)
```

I suppose that your query is not retrieving the 3 records as `votes.user_id` is null for them.

Comment: Yup, should have thought of that additional case where the votes.user_id is null. Thanks!

Comment: Also, stylistically, I am wondering if there is a way to use the ActiveRecord "hash" style instead of passing in the SQL-like string?

Comment: Although this is an old question, I stumbled upon it having a similar problem. I believe this answer is wrong, because the condition 'votes.user_id <> ? or ...' will find any post, where "not only the user" has voted. E.g. it will erroneously return posts, where the user has already voted if another user has voted as well.